# Basic inequality involving sin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Show that

$$ \frac{|t|}{\pi} \leq |\sin (\frac{t}{2})| , t \in [- \pi , \pi]$$

What I tried:  I took $ f(t) = \sin^2 (\frac{t}{2})  - \frac{t^2}{\pi^2}$ and I am trying to study if the function increases or decreases in the interval $[- \pi , \pi]$ . But it's not working. Someone can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By symmetry, you need only consider $t\geqslant 0$. Look at the values for $t=0$ and $t=\pi$, and at the graphs of the two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By parity reason it suffices to show the inequality on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

The function $t\mapsto \sin\left(\frac t 2\right)$ is **concave** on $[0,\pi]$  *(its second derivative is non positive)* so  its curve is above the segment joining the two points of the curve $(0,0)$ and $(\pi,1)$ with equation $y=\frac 1 \pi t$ hence we conclude.